# What causes a duplicate web.config under the obj output folder after publishing an MVC3 app?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, publish

Often after publishing my MVC3 app, using a file system publish, when I next try to run the app in the VS2010 debugger, I get the error: *It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.* I get this because my web.config file has been duplicated in a folder called *obj\debugrelease\package\packagetmp\web.config*, where *debugrelease* is the name of the build config I am publishing to. Simply deleting the whole *obj* folder solves this issue, but I'm annoyed that it happens and can't help wondering what is wrong.

Comment: The obj folder shouldn't be published. What is your 'Items to deploy' set to in the package/publish settings?

Comment: @BNL The obj folder isn't published, but the publishing process creates this artefact in the object folder. I get the error running the solution, not the published output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?:

- Looking at *project properties >> Package/Publish Web tab* to see if there is anything not set quite right, for instance I have "Deploy only files needed to run this application".
- Showing all files in your project to make sure you haven't got web.config files hiding somewhere other than your *obj* folder.
- Opening your project file in a text editor to see if the config is referencing a web.config file somewhere it shouldn't?